# Visio 2013 Describing Sub-activities with Call Behavior Actions

Tags: uml, visio, activity-diagram

I use Visio 2013.I have to describing Sub-activities with Call Behavior Actions in Activity diagram.But I do not how I can do that..It may be seems like this:

[image]

I searched in Google and found [Describing Sub-activities with Call Behavior Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409465.aspx) but it is in about **Visual Studio 2013**.Do you know how I can do that in Visio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-IuGdvNbNQ) (the introduction with the use case is quite disappointing), the representation of sub-activities with Visio seems less integrated with the tool than in Visual Studio, but possible anyway.

It worked with Visio 2007. Should work with Visio 2013...

Comment: OK! I saw that but it seems there is no thing like `link` between diagrams.Did I understand it correctly?